# How to merge multiple lists into one list in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying merge multiple lists into one list

e.g:`['of', 'participants:', '25']['participants:', '25', 'we']['25', 'we', 'require']`

after code:" `['of', 'participants:', '25'],['participants:', '25', 'we'],['25', 'we', 'require']`"

```
for wrd in d:
    child=child.lower()
    child=child.replace(' ','')
    dat =child
    r = re.compile(dat)
    s=str(wrd)
    test=[sentence in dat for sentence in s]
    if r.search(s) and any(test):
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm again I'm not entirely sure what your doing. Looking at your code your using a regex. Maybe it would be better to use a dictionary. If you must use a list you could incorporate it into a tuple like so with a loop. Let me know if it helps.

```
>>> list_one = ['of', 'participants:', '25']
>>> list_two = ['participants:', '25', 'we']
>>> list_three = ['25', 'we', 'require']
>>> thing = ()
>>> thing += tuple([list_one])
>>> thing += tuple([list_two])
>>> thing += tuple([list_three])
>>> thing
(['of', 'participants:', '25'], ['participants:', '25', 'we'], ['25', 'we', 'require'])
>>> for i in range(len(thing)):
...     print thing[i]
... 
['of', 'participants:', '25']
['participants:', '25', 'we']
['25', 'we', 'require']
```

Comment: s=str(wrd)
        test=[sentence in dat for sentence in s]
        if r.search(s) and any(test):
            print(s)  .... i'm getting ['of', 'participants:', '25']
['participants:', '25', 'we']
['25', 'we', 'require'] but i need output as ['of', 'participants:', '25'] ,
['participants:', '25', 'we'], 
['25', 'we', 'require']

Comment: Let me know if that helps I think thats what your asking

Comment: listone=['of', 'participants:', '25'] ['participants:', '25', 'we'] ['25', 'we', 'require'] this is how i'm getting